# 96 Volkswagon climate control wont work

Tags: vw, heat, climate-control

We were driving down the road and all the sudden a puff of smoke came from ignition area, and the climate control stopped working. It has no power at all. I have checked relays, checked fuses, even replaced the ignition switch. Even pulled the dash to check for burnt wires and was checking for broke wires with a meter. I am at a loss. I can't find anything wrong. It's just dead with no power at all.

Comment: Knowing the year and model of your car would help tremendously.